# Apache как включить AllowOverride через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

хочу включить .htaccess httpd.conf установлен `AllowOverride none`. Но когда хочу поменять выдает ошибку 1001, написал в тп, они мне говорят задать AllowOverride через .htaccess, но разве так можно? И как это сделать?

Comment: Через htaccess нельзя, через подключенные `Include` конфигурации можно

Comment: @DiD Понял, что тп, очень умные ребята, подскажите как можно подключить конфигурации и где их лучше располагать apache24? Стоит Wordpress

Comment: Я ваш хостинг не настраивал. Так конечно сложно сказать какие пути у папки с конфигами прописаны в `httpd.conf`. Но вы можете прочитать его, он наверняка доступен для чтения. Вам надо найти вот [такие операторы](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) в этом файле. `*.conf` означает подключать все скрипты находящиеся в папке.

Comment: А вот тут можно найти дефолтные адреса главного конфига https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout

Comment: @DiD большое спасибо